# How to use takeWhile with an Iterator in Scala

Tags: scala, iterator, iteration

I have a Iterator of elements and I want to consume them until a condition is met in the next element, like:

```
val it = List(1,1,1,1,2,2,2).iterator
val res1 = it.takeWhile( _ == 1).toList
val res2 = it.takeWhile(_ == 2).toList
```

`res1` gives an expected `List(1,1,1,1)` but `res2` returns `List(2,2)` because iterator had to check the element in position 4.

I know that the list will be ordered so there is no point in traversing the whole list like `partition` does. I like to finish as soon as the condition is not met. Is there any clever way to do this with Iterators? I can not do a `toList` to the iterator because it comes from a very big file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With my other answer (which I've left separate as they are largely unrelated), I think you can implement `groupWhen` on `Iterator` as follows:

```
def groupWhen[A](itr: Iterator[A])(p: (A, A) => Boolean): Iterator[List[A]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec 
  def groupWhen0(acc: Iterator[List[A]], itr: Iterator[A])(p: (A, A) => Boolean): Iterator[List[A]] = {
    val (dup1, dup2) = itr.duplicate
    val pref = ((dup1.sliding(2) takeWhile { case Seq(a1, a2) => p(a1, a2) }).zipWithIndex collect {
      case (seq, 0)       => seq
      case (Seq(_, a), _) => Seq(a)
    }).flatten.toList
    val newAcc = if (pref.isEmpty) acc else acc ++ Iterator(pref)
    if (dup2.nonEmpty)
      groupWhen0(newAcc, dup2 drop (pref.length max 1))(p)
    else newAcc
  }
  groupWhen0(Iterator.empty, itr)(p)
}
```

When I run it on an example:

```
println( groupWhen(List(1,1,1,1,3,4,3,2,2,2).iterator)(_ == _).toList )
```

I get `List(List(1, 1, 1, 1), List(2, 2, 2))`

Comment: Beware that this implementation will drop the elements where the predicate return false. Better use borice implementation.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution I found:

```
val it = List(1,1,1,1,2,2,2).iterator
val (r1, it2) = it.span( _ == 1)

println(s"group taken is: ${r1.toList}\n rest is: ${it2.toList}")
```

output:

```
group taken is: List(1, 1, 1, 1)
rest is: List(2, 2, 2)
```

Very short but further you have to use new iterator.

With any immutable collection it would be similar:

- use takeWhile when you want only some prefix of collection,
- use span when you need rest also.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar need, but the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17705111/1112620) from @oxbow_lakes does not take into account the situation when the list has only one element, or even if the list contains elements that are not repeated. Also, that solution doesn't lend itself well to an infinite iterator (it wants to "see" all the elements before it gives you a result).

What I needed was the ability to group sequential elements that match a predicate, but also include the single elements (I can always filter them out if I don't need them). I needed those groups to be delivered continuously, without having to wait for the original iterator to be completely consumed before they are produced.

I came up with the following approach which works for my needs, and thought I should share:

```
implicit class IteratorEx[+A](itr: Iterator[A]) {
  def groupWhen(p: (A, A) => Boolean): Iterator[List[A]] = new AbstractIterator[List[A]] {
    val (it1, it2) = itr.duplicate
    val ritr = new RewindableIterator(it1, 1)

    override def hasNext = it2.hasNext

    override def next() = {
      val count = (ritr.rewind().sliding(2) takeWhile {
        case Seq(a1, a2) => p(a1, a2)
        case _ => false
      }).length

      (it2 take (count + 1)).toList
    }
  }
}
```

The above is using a few helper classes:

```
abstract class AbstractIterator[A] extends Iterator[A]

/**
 * Wraps a given iterator to add the ability to remember the last 'remember' values
 * From any position the iterator can be rewound (can go back) at most 'remember' values,
 * such that when calling 'next()' the memoized values will be provided as if they have not
 * been iterated over before.
 */
class RewindableIterator[A](it: Iterator[A], remember: Int) extends Iterator[A] {
  private var memory = List.empty[A]
  private var memoryIndex = 0

  override def next() = {
    if (memoryIndex < memory.length) {
      val next = memory(memoryIndex)
      memoryIndex += 1
      next
    } else {
      val next = it.next()
      memory = memory :+ next
      if (memory.length > remember)
        memory = memory drop 1
      memoryIndex = memory.length
      next
    }
  }

  def canRewind(n: Int) = memoryIndex - n >= 0

  def rewind(n: Int) = {
    require(memoryIndex - n >= 0, "Attempted to rewind past 'remember' limit")
    memoryIndex -= n
    this
  }

  def rewind() = {
    memoryIndex = 0
    this
  }

  override def hasNext = it.hasNext
}
```

Example use:

```
List(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5).iterator.groupWhen(_ == _).toList
```

gives: `List(List(1), List(2, 2), List(3, 3, 3), List(4), List(5, 5))`
If you want to filter out the single elements, just apply a `filter` or `withFilter` after `groupWhen`

```
Stream.continually(Random.nextInt(100)).iterator
      .groupWhen(_ + _ == 100).withFilter(_.length > 1).take(3).toList
```

gives: `List(List(34, 66), List(87, 13), List(97, 3))`

Comment: `List(1,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,1).iterator.groupWhen(_ == _).toList == List(List(1), List(2, 2), List(3, 3, 3), List(2, 2), List(1))`. Lovely.
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/h0jiqWU0Sp21pE6pcrWQIA

Answer (score 0):

You could use method `toStream` on `Iterator`.

`Stream` is a lazy equivalent of `List`.

As you can see from [implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L1142-1144) of `toStream` it creates a `Stream` without traversing the whole `Iterator`.

`Stream` keeps all element in memory. You should localize usage of link to `Stream` in some local scope to prevent memory leaking.

With `Stream` you should use `span` like this:

```
val (res1, rest1) = stream.span(_ == 1)
val (res2, rest2) = rest1.span(_ == 2)
```

Comment: But Stream has huge drawback one has to know: unlike iterator it **keeps all items** he has read in memory.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: OP needs all items if he wants to reiterate on collection. And `Stream` keeps elements only while there is a link to first element.

Comment: But then the first time I execute the takeWhile I get a Stream(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, ?) and the second takeWhile starts again from the begining of the Stream(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, ?) giving an empty Stream

Comment: @ancechu: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. If you want the same behavior as with `Iterator` you could use `span` method of `Stream`, but it's better to use `Iterator`, as @om-nom-nom mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit here but by the statement *"until a condition is met in the next element"*, it sounds like you might want to look at the `groupWhen` method on `ListOps` in **scalaz**

```
scala> import scalaz.syntax.std.list._
import scalaz.syntax.std.list._

scala> List(1,1,1,1,2,2,2) groupWhen (_ == _)
res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 1, 1, 1), List(2, 2, 2))
```

Basically this "chunks" up the input sequence upon a condition (a `(A, A) => Boolean`) being met between an element and its successor. In the example above the condition is equality, so, as long as an element is equal to its successor, they will be in the same chunk.

Comment: Yes, that's the functionality I'm looking for, but the problem is that I can't hold in memory the result of the groupWhen. I'm getting values through an iterator reading lines from a big file. Does a groupWhen for iterators exists in scalaz?

Comment: No - scalaz does not "like" iterators (they are not pure). They have a class called `EphemeralStream`. It doesn't come with a `groupWhen` but you could write one easily enough, given that it's a *monad*. I wouldn't guarantee it won't overflow the stack though!

Comment: I've added a different answer below, showing how you can add groupBy to an Iterator by making use of the `iterator.duplicate` functionality.